# Run command in cmd from Ruby

Tags: ruby, cmd, chef-infra

I know this is probably a really simple question, but I am having a really hard time finding a solution. I am working on windows in cmd. I am simply trying to use this command:

```
find /i \"chef_server_url\" C:/chef/client.rb
```

I know the command works. It simply returns a url in a file that I wanted to check.

I want to execute this in code and return the results in my code. But I am having a hard time formatting the string especially with the escape characters

I am using `%x[]` to do so. So ideally I would just say
`%x[find /i \"chef_server_url\" C:/chef/client.rb]`

But the `c:/chef/client.rb` will not format correctly because it thinks /c and /c are not supposed to be that way

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Ruby instead of shelling out?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd use ruby.. honestly i am just new to ruby and just was trying to use what I know how to do...

Comment: HOw would I just use Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to access the Chef Server URL from inside Chef? You can use `Chef::Config[:chef_server_url]` but the deeper question is what you trying to do?

Comment: well, you just solved my question haha.. thats exactly what I was trying to do.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that there is more than one way to run a system command in ruby:

- The [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method takes a plain string, so as long as you can get your command accurately represented in a string, it should work. Something like `system 'find /i "chef_server_url" C:/chef/client.rb'` should work.
- Backticks will do similar, which should look something like this: `find /i "chef_server_url" c:/chef/client.rb` (wrap in `backticks`, I'm not sure how to format on StackExchange).

I'd first recommend getting a string representation of your command, `puts` it out, copy paste to a command window. If it works, then send it through `system`.

However, like others here, I suspect there is a better solution to the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

I'm not anywhere near a windows computer for testing, so you'll have to experiment with these.

Comment: While correct for Ruby, this is wrong for Chef where we use a different gem for command execution.